# Strange icon in all system password boxes on Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: macos, mojave, password, ui

For a few days, I've been seeing this very strange icon every time a system password box shows up. I have no idea what it means? Does anyone know? I do not have capslock on.

[image: password box]

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are running? Additionally, try toggling the caps lock key on the keyboard and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I'm running Mojave 10.14.6. Toggling capslock has no effect.

Comment: What kind of keyboard are you using? Try toggling the NumLock key if present on your keyboard.

Comment: I'm using a typematrix 2030, which has a numlock key, but the icon remains here even when no keyboard is attached. Regardless of what causes this icon to display, i'd like to know what it _means_

Comment: It most likely means that the Num Lock key is depressed. Disconnecting the keyboard won't toggle it. Try re-connecting the keyboard and toggling the Num Lock key.

Comment: I tried toggling the numlock key on my keyboard (which happens to be on the function layer), and it has no effect.

Comment: Please post the answer as a, well, answer below and mark it as accepted afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a "Numlock" icon. Rebooting the machine made it disappear. What made it appear in the first place remains a mystery...